# Install bundle on Laravel 4.x

Tags: laravel

How install a bundle on Laravel project if no command is defined on bundle namespace.
I tried with:

```
php artisan bundle:install charisma
```

and I get

```
[InvalidArgumentException]                                
  There are no commands defined in the "bundle" namespace.
```

Comment: Laravel 4 does not support bundles anymore. Use [composer](https://getcomposer.org/) with [packagist](https://packagist.org/).

Answer (score 6):

Laravel 4 doesn't use Bundles. It uses packages that are distributed via Packagist and Composer

You can read more about Laravel Packages here:

http://laravel.com/docs/packages